# CherryPy won't start

Tags: python, python-2.7, cherrypy

I'm having some trouble starting CherryPy and I can't figure out why I keep getting this error. Here's the versions and the related code with log output.

Python 2.7.6
CherryPy 3.5.0 (via PIP)

```
CURRENT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
STATIC_DIR = os.path.join(CURRENT_DIR, "static")
CONFIG = {
    '/static': {
        'tools.staticdir.on': True,
        'tools.staticdir.dir': STATIC_DIR
    }
}

Daemonizer(cherrypy.engine).subscribe()                         # When we start, do it as a daemon process
cherrypy.config.update({'server.socket_host': '127.0.0.1','server.socket_port': 8080,'log.error_file': 'site.log'})       # Listen on all local IPs (default is 8080)
cherrypy.tree.mount(MyWebServer(), '/', config=CONFIG)          # Mount the app on the root
cherrypy.engine.start()
```

here's the log output:

```
[05/Jul/2014:10:28:01] ENGINE Bus STARTING
[05/Jul/2014:10:28:01] ENGINE Forking once.
[05/Jul/2014:10:28:01] ENGINE Forking twice.
[05/Jul/2014:10:28:01] ENGINE Daemonized to PID: 21464
[05/Jul/2014:10:28:01] ENGINE Started monitor thread 'Monitor'.
[05/Jul/2014:10:28:01] ENGINE Started monitor thread 'Autoreloader'.
[05/Jul/2014:10:28:01] ENGINE Started monitor thread 'Monitor'.
[05/Jul/2014:10:28:01] ENGINE Started monitor thread 'Monitor'.
[05/Jul/2014:10:28:01] ENGINE Started monitor thread 'Monitor'.
[05/Jul/2014:10:28:01] ENGINE Started monitor thread '_TimeoutMonitor'.
[05/Jul/2014:10:28:01] ENGINE Error in 'start' listener <bound method Server.start of <cherrypy._cpserver.Server object at 0x10cf2d190>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/cherrypy/process/wspbus.py", line 205, in publish
    output.append(listener(*args, **kwargs))
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/cherrypy/_cpserver.py", line 167, in start
    self.httpserver, self.bind_addr = self.httpserver_from_self()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/cherrypy/_cpserver.py", line 158, in httpserver_from_self
    httpserver = _cpwsgi_server.CPWSGIServer(self)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/cherrypy/_cpwsgi_server.py", line 43, in __init__
    accepted_queue_timeout=self.server_adapter.accepted_queue_timeout,
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'accepted_queue_size'

[05/Jul/2014:10:28:01] ENGINE Shutting down due to error in start listener:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/cherrypy/process/wspbus.py", line 243, in start
    self.publish('start')
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/cherrypy/process/wspbus.py", line 223, in publish
    raise exc
ChannelFailures: TypeError("__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'accepted_queue_size'",)

[05/Jul/2014:10:28:01] ENGINE Bus STOPPING
[05/Jul/2014:10:28:01] ENGINE HTTP Server None already shut down
[05/Jul/2014:10:28:01] ENGINE Stopped thread '_TimeoutMonitor'.
[05/Jul/2014:10:28:01] ENGINE Stopped thread 'Monitor'.
[05/Jul/2014:10:28:01] ENGINE Stopped thread 'Monitor'.
[05/Jul/2014:10:28:01] ENGINE Stopped thread 'Autoreloader'.
[05/Jul/2014:10:28:01] ENGINE Stopped thread 'Monitor'.
[05/Jul/2014:10:28:01] ENGINE Stopped thread 'Monitor'.
[05/Jul/2014:10:28:01] ENGINE Bus STOPPED
[05/Jul/2014:10:28:01] ENGINE Bus EXITING
[05/Jul/2014:10:28:01] ENGINE Bus EXITED
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess `Daemonizer` presence indicates you're actually asking about *CherryPy*  deployment.

First, `cherrypy.engine.start()` is not enough to start *CherryPy*. Take a look at `cherrypy.quickstart` for the minimal routine. I put it under `__name__ == '__main__'` condition. It allows you to directly execute the script from shell.

Second, you shouldn't probably deal with `Daemonizer` plugin (and `PIDFile`, `DropPrivileges`, etc) directly in your application code. There's [cherryd](https://cherrypy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/install.html?#cherryd) which should deal with system stuff.

You can run the code below (put in static.py, `cd` to the containing directory) by `cherryd -i static`. It will start your app in foreground. `cherryd -d -i static` will daemonize your app.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


import os

import cherrypy


path   = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
config = {
  'global' : {
    'server.socket_host' : '127.0.0.1',
    'server.socket_port' : 8080,
    'server.thread_pool' : 4
  },
  '/static' : {
    'tools.staticdir.on'  : True,
    'tools.staticdir.dir' : os.path.join(path, 'static')
  }
}

class App:

  @cherrypy.expose
  def index(self):
    return 'Your dynamic stuff'


cherrypy.tree.mount(App(), '/', config)


if __name__ == '__main__':
  cherrypy.engine.signals.subscribe()
  cherrypy.engine.start()
  cherrypy.engine.block()
```

I wrote a complete *CherryPy* deployment tutorial, [cherrypy-webapp-skeleton](https://bitbucket.org/saaj/cherrypy-webapp-skeleton), a couple of years ago. Take a look if you need a complete picture.

Comment: This seems to have worked like a charm. Though for some reason cherryd wasn't installed when I installed cherrypy via pip so I just grabbed it from your Google Code repo :).