# Error starting test CherryPy script

Tags: python, web-applications, cherrypy

I've just recently learned about CherryPy and wanted to incorporate it into some of my web applications. After downloading and installing CherryPy I ran the tutorial test as indicated in the docs using the command:

```
python -m cherrypy.tutorial.tut01_helloworld
```

It produced the following output:

```
[27/Feb/2015:12:11:08] ENGINE Listening for SIGTERM.
[27/Feb/2015:12:11:08] ENGINE Bus STARTING
[27/Feb/2015:12:11:08] ENGINE Set handler for console events.
[27/Feb/2015:12:11:08] ENGINE Started monitor thread '_TimeoutMonitor'.
[27/Feb/2015:12:11:08] ENGINE Started monitor thread 'Autoreloader'.
[27/Feb/2015:12:11:08] ENGINE Error in 'start' listener <bound method Server.start of <cherrypy._cpserver.Server object at 0x0000000002F63518>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\cherrypy\process\wspbus.py", line 205, in publish
output.append(listener(*args, **kwargs))
File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\cherrypy\_cpserver.py", line 167, in start
self.httpserver, self.bind_addr = self.httpserver_from_self()
File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\cherrypy\_cpserver.py", line 158, in httpserver_from_self
httpserver = _cpwsgi_server.CPWSGIServer(self)
File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\cherrypy\_cpwsgi_server.py", line 43, in __init__
accepted_queue_timeout=self.server_adapter.accepted_queue_timeout,
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'accepted_queue_size'

[27/Feb/2015:12:11:08] ENGINE Shutting down due to error in start listener:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\cherrypy\process\wspbus.py", line 243, in start
self.publish('start')
File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\cherrypy\process\wspbus.py", line 223,   in publish
raise exc
ChannelFailures: TypeError("__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'accepted_queue_size'",)
```

Because it's a test from CherryPy I suspect I am missing some dependency but after reviewing the installation docs of the site it didn't say it had any dependencies for basic, simple scripts. I checked stackoverflow but couldn't find anything that matched. 
Has anyone seen this before? I am running on Windows 7, python 2.7, and CherryPy 3.6.

Thanks!

Comment: This guy explains your problem... http://stackoverflow.com/a/24589114/884345

Comment: Hm, your command works every way I try it. Can you reproduce it in a virtual environment?